# Can I enter Haneda Airport without a ticket?

Tags: airports, japan, tokyo, hnd

Is it permitted to enter the Haneda Airport without actually flying? I know that Narita Airport has a checkpoint right after the train station, but is it same for Haneda?

To be specific, I'm interested in visiting their [observation deck](http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/en/premises/service/others.html)

Comment: Worst case scenario: buy a refundable ticket and cancel it after passing the checkpoint.

Comment: You may wish to state in the question International or Domestic Terminals as both have observation decks. If it wasn't for the link, you cannot ascertain which airport you wish to enter. Here is the observation desk in the domestic airport (it offers a less obstructed view) http://www.tokyo-airport-bldg.co.jp/en/service_facilities/view_deck/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**, the observation deck of Haneda's international terminal is the public landside area and open to all.

Incidentally, Narita stopped doing checks on entry some time ago, but even when they were doing them, they wanted only ID, not tickets. Plenty of people visit airports to meet or see off passengers.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, you can enter without a ticket.

I entered that airport many times and was never asked for a ticket before heading to my flight.

I could have been lucky every single time, but then please consider that the airport's building hosts **conference rooms** and a wedding hall. It is obvious that at least some of the attendees will not hold a ticket.

Haneda is marketing itself as a **food destination** by itself. Read the reviews for [this restaurant](https://tabelog.com/tokyo/A1315/A131504/13021855/) for instance, and you will find many reviews like "I decided to go to that restaurant. It is situated within Haneda Airport", mentioning they went there for the food, unrelated to any air travel.